# Issues with drawing over things (libGDX)

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm making a game with water and a boat and I'm drawing the water before the drawing of the boat but the drawing of the boat still isn't being shown. If I don't draw the water the boat will be shown so it isn't an issue with drawing itself.

Water Class:

```
package com.lance.seajam;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Matrix4;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Disposable;

public class Water extends ApplicationAdapter implements Disposable {
    private static final float TEXTURE_REPEATS_HORIZONTAL = 5f;
    private static final float NOISE_SPEED_HORIZONTAL = 0.04f;
    private static final Matrix4 IDT = new Matrix4();

    private final Texture waterTexture;
    private final Texture noiseTexture;
    private final SpriteBatch batch;
    private ShaderProgram shaderProgram;

    private final String vertexShaderString = Gdx.files.internal("shaders/water/mainvs.glsl").readString();
    private final String fragmentShaderString = Gdx.files.internal("shaders/water/mainfs.glsl").readString();

    private void compileShader() {
        shaderProgram = new ShaderProgram(vertexShaderString, fragmentShaderString);
        if (!shaderProgram.isCompiled()) {
            System.out.println(shaderProgram.getLog());
        }
    }

    public Water(SpriteBatch batch, String imgDir) {
        this.batch = batch;
        waterTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(imgDir + "/water.png"));
        noiseTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(imgDir + "/noise.png"));

        noiseTexture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat); // make the texture repeat
        waterTexture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat); // make the texture repeat

        waterTexture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
        noiseTexture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);

        compileShader();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        waterTexture.dispose();
        noiseTexture.dispose();
        shaderProgram.dispose();
    }

    float time = 0f;
    public void Draw() {
        time += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); // Gets how much seconds has passed

        shaderProgram.bind();

        float screenRatio = ((float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth()) / ((float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        shaderProgram.setUniformf("u_texCoordScale", TEXTURE_REPEATS_HORIZONTAL, TEXTURE_REPEATS_HORIZONTAL / screenRatio);
        shaderProgram.setUniformf("u_noise_scale", 0.1f);
        shaderProgram.setUniformf("u_noise_scroll_velocity", NOISE_SPEED_HORIZONTAL, NOISE_SPEED_HORIZONTAL / screenRatio);
        shaderProgram.setUniformf("u_distortion", 0.04f);
        shaderProgram.setUniformf("u_time", time);

        noiseTexture.bind(0);

        batch.begin();
            batch.setProjectionMatrix(IDT);
            batch.enableBlending();
            batch.setShader(shaderProgram);
            batch.draw(waterTexture, -1f, 1f, 2f, -2f); // screen-covering square for identity matrix
        batch.end();

        batch.setShader(null);
    }
}
```

Player Class:

```
package com.lance.seajam;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;

public class Player {
    private final float rotSpeed;
    private final float movementSpeed;

    private final Texture texture;
    private final int textureWidth;
    private final int textureHeight;
    public final SpriteBatch batch;
    private Vector2 position;
    private Vector2 direction = new Vector2(Vector2.X);
    private int rotation;
    private final float originX;
    private final float originY;

    public Player(Texture texture, SpriteBatch batch) {
        this.texture = texture;
        this.batch = batch;
        this.rotation = 0;
        this.textureWidth = texture.getWidth();
        this.textureHeight = texture.getHeight();
        this.position = new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 + texture.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 + texture.getHeight()/2);

        this.originX = textureWidth/2.0f;
        this.originY = textureHeight/2.0f;
        this.rotSpeed = 200f;
        this.movementSpeed = 300f;
    }

    public void Movement(double deltaTime) {
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)) rotation += rotSpeed * deltaTime;
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D)) rotation -= rotSpeed * deltaTime;

        direction.set(Vector2.X).rotateDeg(rotation);

        direction.scl(movementSpeed); // Scale the direction by your speed

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W)) {
            position.x += direction.x * deltaTime;
            position.y += direction.y * deltaTime;
        } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.S)) {
            position.x -= direction.x * deltaTime;
            position.y -= direction.y * deltaTime;
        }

    }

    public void DrawSprite() {
        batch.begin();
            batch.draw (
                texture, position.x, position.y,
                originX, originY, textureWidth,
                textureHeight, 1, 1,
                rotation, 1, 1, textureWidth,
                textureHeight, false, false
            );
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

GameScreen Class:

```
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    water.Draw();
    player.DrawSprite();
    player.Movement(delta);
}
```

Is there anyway that I can make the boat draw over the water? I also need to add trash to my game later on so please explain aswell. I've tried Gdx.gl.glEnableBlending, switching the methods of which draws first and using different batches but all of them don't work.

Comment: Are both the `Water` and the `Player` using the same `SpriteBatch`?

Comment: No, they are using copies.

Comment: Can you show how and where you set the projection matrix for the `SpriteBatch` that the `Player` is using?

Comment: It doesn’t have one. Now that I really think about it, it should probably have one

Comment: Not related to what you asked about, but SpriteBatch exclusively uses texture unit 0 for the texture you pass to it, but it also assumes the current unit is zero. So if you multitexture like this, you must bind the second texture to unit 1 and then immediately switch the active unit back to zero.

Comment: @Tenfour04, Thanks! I'll take note of that. I'm pretty new to libGDX.

Comment: Also a tip for drawing your sprites. The water is a special case because it’s a full screen effect with a unique shader. But most of your other sprites you will want to batch into a single OpenGL draw call, which means you don’t want to be beginning and ending your batch or setting the projection matrix inside this player class. It should just call batch.draw(). The begin/end/setProjectionMatrix calls should be in your GameScreen class so all your sprite related classes can be drawn using a single projection in between a single begin/end.

Comment: Right! I didn’t think about that.

Answer (score 0):

When using a `SpriteBatch` to draw something you need to set the projection matrix for the batch. This is done by calling `SpriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix` passing in a `Matrix4` containing the projection.

Often, this is done by taking the `combined` matrix of a `Camera`:

```
OrthographicCamera camera = new OrthographicCamera( ... );
// Some initialization

spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined)
```

Make sure the `SpriteBatch` has a valid projection matrix for a view that contains the `Player`'s coordinates.